# How to work out my hardware's hashrate power

Tags: mining-hardware, hash, hashpower, scrypt, sha256

Using my existing hardware, I want to work out which altcoin is still profitable to mine.

I have found this link:

http://dustcoin.com/mining

But don't know which values to enter into the boxes at the bottom of that page.

1. How do I work out the SHA-256 and scrypt hashrate
2. For the Power(W) box, do I enter in my computers PSU wattage? I think it's 650w
3. For the Power Cost ($/kWh) box, do I check my electricity bill to find out how much I am paying per kWh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I work out the SHA-256 and scrypt hashrate

You can look up your hardware e.g. [here (BTC)](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison) and [here (LTC)](https://litecoin.info/Mining_hardware_comparison). But I think it's much easier and more accurate to just try mining different coins for couple hours and measure hashrate directly.

> For the Power(W) box, do I enter in my computers PSU wattage? I think it's 650w

PSU wattage is max. power it can supply, so it poses upper bound on PCs consumption. 
To get accurate measurements, you can use something like [Kill-a-Watt](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001JHGY2Q). Or you can look up TDP of individual components: CPU's, GPU's and ASIS's power consumption is usually listed in their specs, and motherboard+RAM+HDD together usually use around 50W.

> For the Power Cost ($/kWh) box, do I check my electricity bill to find out how much I am paying per kWh?

Yes.